# web service to web service integratrion with WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2, I wanted to do integration to WS to WS. wanted to call other webservice from one existing web service. For second web service call we have different schema so due to that I need to map existing request to the new schema. So that I can call second web service.

I am finding out how to do it, currently there is enrich mediator which can be do such chaneges in xml, but not sure how to use it.

do anybody have idea about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to WSO2 ESB, I think you should look at [ESB Samples](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Samples). There are many samples including Enrich mediator.

For your scenario, you should be able to use the [Payload Factory Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator). Please refer the [sample for Payload Factory Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136018).

Also look at [Enterprise Integration Patterns with WSO2 ESB](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Enterprise+Integration+Patterns+with+WSO2+ESB). You may look at [Message Translator pattern](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Message+Translator).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks It is working with payload mediator for xml to xml transformation, but I have tried with smooks mediator and smooks configuration, I am not able to run it successfully. Using smooks it is far more easy as graphical mapping can be possible with smooks. I have posted issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796661/xml-to-xml-transformation-with-wso2

Comment: Yes, Smooks mediator is another way to transform messages.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of graphical mapping can be done with smooks is as in below screen shot,

[image]